# how to use gstreamer in a qt project on Windows?

Tags: c++, c, qt, gstreamer

[Here you can find a qt project to reproduce the problem](https://gitlab.com/njager/gstreamer-test/tree/master)

I need to use **gstreamer** inside a **Qt/Qml** application. I installed **gstreamer-1.0-devel-x86_64-1.14.3** and **gstreamer-1.0-x86_64-1.14.3**

For some reason **GST_PLUGIN_PATH** is not set. I set it myself with `putenv()`.

I got a lot of warnings, see below the first ones,

```
(gstreamer-test.exe:8540): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgsta52dec.dll': 'C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgsta52dec.dll': The specified module could not be found.

(gstreamer-test.exe:8540): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstaccurip.dll': 'C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstaccurip.dll': The specified module could not be found.

(gstreamer-test.exe:8540): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstadder.dll': 'C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstadder.dll': The specified module could not be found.
```

In the code I try to make several `GstElement`,

```
/* Create gstreamer elements */
GstElement *pipeline, *source, *demuxer, *decoder, *conv, *sink;
pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("audio-player");
source   = gst_element_factory_make ("filesrc",       "file-source");
demuxer  = gst_element_factory_make ("oggdemux",      "ogg-demuxer");
decoder  = gst_element_factory_make ("vorbisdec",     "vorbis-decoder");
conv     = gst_element_factory_make ("audioconvert",  "converter");
sink     = gst_element_factory_make ("autoaudiosink", "audio-output");
```

then I check for each `GstElement` if they was well build. The result show,

```
source == nullptr
demuxer == nullptr
decoder == nullptr
conv == nullptr
```

which for example, in the case of `source` means the `factoryname` `filesrc` was not found.

but `gst-inspect-1.0.exe` found it as show the screenshot,
[image]

and in the meantime, the `factoryname` `autoaudiosink` work.

to finish, I got several critical messages,

```
(gstreamer-test.exe:8540): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(gstreamer-test.exe:8540): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_bin_add: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed

(gstreamer-test.exe:8540): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_get_static_pad: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed

(gstreamer-test.exe:8540): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_object_unref: assertion 'object != NULL' failed
```

no clue about why I got them...

*note: since [qt-gstreamer](https://github.com/GStreamer/qt-gstreamer) is unmaintained I didn't tried it.*

Comment: Have you included appropriate headers in your code? Also did you link the library while compiling? For eg: `gcc basic-tutorial-1.c -o basic-tutorial-1 ` `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0`

Comment: I guess so, otherwise it would have errors at compile or link time. The thing I'm sure, I have `-LC:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\lib -lglib-2.0`. For the headers I have `C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\include\gstreamer-1.0`, `C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\include\glib-2.0`, `C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\lib\glib-2.0\include`. Note: I'm linux user and dev, but right  now I have to work on windows. So I may miss something...

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but have you looked into [Qt Multimedia](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qtmultimedia-index.html)?

Comment: @MrEricSir yes I did. I failed to screen my MJPEG source (ip camera). wich seems not working with QtMultimedia.